# Hide "Load More" link when no more posts to load

Tags: jquery

This is a follow up on my previous post, now with different code.

I got this working, it loads the content I want, all the pages (see [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990197/jquery-load-content-return-no-more-than-current-next-page-i-want-more-pages-t)). I have 9 pages (standard WP archive where I use next_posts_link as "anchor" for the click.

But when page 9 is load, I click "Load More" and it keeps loading page 9....I want it to stop and hide the "load more" link. Any help much appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $content = '#upplevelser';
var $nav_wrap = '.navigation';
var $anchor = '.navigation .nav-previous a';
var $text = 'Load More';
var $next_href = $($anchor).attr('href'); // Get URL for the next set of posts
$($nav_wrap).html('<a id="nav-below" href="' + $next_href + '">' + $text + '</a>');
$('#nav-below a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == "") {
    alert('I am empty href value');
    }

    $.get($(this).attr('href'), '', function(data) {
    var $timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var $new_content = $($content, data).wrapInner('<div class="more-articles-here" id="rtz-' + $timestamp + '" />').html(); // Grab just the content
    $next_href = $($anchor, data).attr('href'); // Get the new href
    $($nav_wrap).before($new_content); // Append the new content
    $('#rtz-' + $timestamp).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Animate load
    $('#nav-below a').attr('href', $next_href); // Change the next URL
    $('.more-articles-here ' + $nav_wrap).remove(); // Remove the original navigation

    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit to fit your requirement and its fine on my localhost installation..

Here is the used I have used.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $content = '#upplevelser';
var $nav_wrap = '.navigation';
var $anchor = '.navigation .nav-previous a';
var $text = 'Load More';
var $next_href = $($anchor).attr('href'); // Get URL for the next set of posts
$($nav_wrap).html('<a id="nav-below" href="' + $next_href + '">' + $text + '</a>');
$('#nav-below a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == "") {
    alert('I am empty href value');
    }

    $.get($(this).attr('href'), '', function(data) {
    var $timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var $new_content = $($content, data).wrapInner('<div class="more-articles-here" id="rtz-' + $timestamp + '" />').html(); // Grab just the content
    $next_href = $($anchor, data).attr('href'); // Get the new href
    $($nav_wrap).before($new_content); // Append the new content
    $('#rtz-' + $timestamp).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Animate load
    $('#nav-below a').attr('href', $next_href); // Change the next URL
    $('.more-articles-here .navigation:last').remove(); // Remove the original navigation

    });
});
});
```

Hope this will work for you as well....